Crystal Reports adding a label to the details section without duplicating the added label
I am new to crystal reports so could you help me with this?
I need to add 2 text objects(Total Net Weight, Total Gross Weight) to the details section of the Crystal report as follows:
         Total Net Weight: (Database Value/Field)
         Total Gross Weight : (Database Value/Field)

Can you tell me how to do this?
When I added a text object, it gets duplicated and messes the entire design layout.
Thank you.
I tried the option "Suppress If Duplicated" through the Format Editor, but it does not help me to get the result I want.
